# Understanding a diagram showing that $1-\cos\theta$ is much smaller than $\theta$ (for small $\theta$)

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I don't get why, with the triangle on the right, the small length on the x-axis is $1-\cos\theta$.

edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvS4M.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The arc is part of a unit circle (radius of $1$) so if one part is $cos\theta$, the other part is $1 - \cos\theta$ (the sum of these two pieces is $1$).

Comment: I posted another link showing the full proof. Do you know why the textbook is checking 1-$cos \theta$ instead of just $cos\theta$?

Comment: What does this have to do with the question you asked?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the question I asked, but I didn't want to make another post on the same proof. And it looks like you know what you're talking about. So that is why I asked you. If you can answer, that would be really appreciated Thank you.

Comment: With SE sites it's actually better to either (a) ask multiple questions, or (b) put more (very closely related) questions in your original question. Asking additional questions in the comments isn't really the way to do it because the comments are more meant to ask for clarification of the questions and answers, not for extended discussion. It's a bit different than in a forum. In fact, if this conversation goes on too long, you'll end up getting an automatic message telling you to avoid this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The radius of the unit circle is 1. Then the length of the side of the right triangle drawn is $\cos\theta$, since 
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}=\text{adjacent}
$$
since the hypotenuse is length one, as it is the radius of the unit circle again.

Comment: Ok... I get it now. But can you explain the tan $\theta$

Comment: @user498021 Use similar triangles.